# js programmatically override method

Tags: javascript, decorator

```
class Collection {
}

class Model extends Collection {
    save() {
        console.log('original Implementation')
    }
}

@Persistable
class User extends Model {
}

function Persistable(target: any) {
    target.save = function () { console.log('override') }
}

let user = new User()
user.save() // prints original Implementation
```

I would like to override a class method using a decorator. Unfortunately the override does not work and the original Method still gets executed

Comment: I guess you want `target.prototype.save`?

Comment: @Bergi Thanks. Stupid mistake. You can post it as an answer and I will accept it